# get a list of a Particular Object in HQL

Tags: java, hibernate, casting, sum, hql

Hello Everybody I´m starting with Hibernate.

I have an object:

Expiration with these attributes:

```
private VencimientoId id;
private Integer in;
private Integer out;
private Integer amount;
```

I want to recieve a list of expiration with the sum some attributes:
So I did this with HQL:

```
 Query query=session.createQuery("SELECT vencimiento.id, "
                               + "sum(Expiration.in),"
                               + "sum(Expiration.out),"
                               + "sum(Expiration.amount) "
                               + "FROM Expiration expiration "
                               + "GROUP BY Expiration.id.name");        
 list=query.list();
 return list;
```

this list is a List;

But when I run the code I recieve an "Object" inside the list instead "Expiration" object (the object is equals to Expiration object but the type of in, out and amount is Long instead Integer).
I know that sum in HQL return Long and that´s why I recieving the Long type instead Integer.
I tried to cast as integer but is giving me an error.

how could I do this?
let me know if you need further information
thank you in advance

Comment: What exactly you want to know? How to cast `Long` to `int`?

Comment: you are returning multiple column sum in the query and as far as I know it will give you a `List<Object[]>` why not just iterate over it and cast it to your required type.

Comment: talex, no. I want to have a list<Expiration>.

I did what silenprogrammer suggest but I thought it would be a better way to do this. I think is not good for performance and I thought it could be a better way to have this list of a particular object

Comment: @DanielNacher I dont think thats a performance issue you want whole object but that include unnessasry column instead just reading particular columns In both the cases you have to iterate over list for first case lot of unwanted column from table is returned.

Comment: @DanielNacher  Thing that you returning is not `Expiration`, it is some statistic based on several instances of it. So do not worry and decode `Object[]` to what you want manually. There will be no performance problem.